# How to make Android app retrieve data daily from the server?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio

I'm making an app for my project in my android studio. I write an app that locate the item in the supermarket.

Now whenever the app is opened within the user's phone. I want the app to be able to retrieve the daily's promotion (.jpeg) of the supermarket into the app.

For instance, there is a button (txt: daily promotion). Whenever the user click this button, the app will load the picture (change daily)  that I created. My question is Is there any free server that I can host my picture? And how can I make my program link to my picture?

Anyone have any idea what would be the easiest way to do this?

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server that sends the photo and the message is a java application I would suggest using [kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet). You can send a packet to the server when the app starts and then program the server to send a packet to the client that contains the message and the image. Then just get the client to display the image and message just like you want! If you need more help just comment and I could explain more.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I need. But I think it a little too complicate. Is there any other way?

Comment: I could give a code example if you want, it may take a hwilenbut I can do it. How much knowledge do youbhave with programmin in general, not in android?

Comment: My programming skill is first year uni. However, I find a way to do it. I got the free webhost for hosting my image then I let the app call the image by URL. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok great idea actually. If you found my answer helpful, could you upvote it please, it mught be of some help to others who have the same issue, thanks!